# What are the names of the antennas which I have marked in this picture of a Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification, antenna

[image]

I have taken the picture from PMDG 737NGX Microsoft flight simulator X. I am really curious to know what this antennas are. These antennas are behind the nose gear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATC, Altimeter Transmitters and Receivers, and DME-1

[image]

Comment: The perfect answer with minimal number of words. Magnificent. Thank you.