# What are these "winglets" on the roof of the 737?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification, fuselage, antenna

I circled the parts on the fuselage in red.[image]

Comment: related: [What are the names of the antennas which I have marked in this picture of a Boeing 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/79480/3394). I though there was already questions about those specific antenna on the B737 here but it seems other questions were about other antenna.

Comment: they're for when you're going sideways really, really fast!

Answer (score 22):

In general, those are called blade antennas. They consist of a [monopole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopole_antenna#Types) (a single rod sticking out of the fuselage) with an aerodynamic fairing around it.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

It looks like a VHF and ELT antenna.

[image]

References:

1. [Boeing 737NG Radio Equipment](https://www.ab9il.net/aviation/737-radio.html)
2. [Communications](http://www.b737.org.uk/communications.htm)